# React Native demo project is failing due to gradle issue

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

Trying to setup the react native on Windows 7 as per instrcutions provided at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html, after installing all the mandatory tools & dependencies, started getting below issue while running `react-native run-android` command.

[image]

Also looked at many options like setting up proxy for `gradle` etc but nothing seems to be worked till now.

Hope to get some quick help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is not a temporary connection issue? Can you ping the server and get a response? Can you open the URL to the resource directly in your browser?

Comment: It's working directly from the browser, so temp connection wouldn't be an issue.